# error after login into WSO2 IOT server device management console

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Error after login into WSO2 IOT server device management console.  The error is coming in when adding users and roles in device management console:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Make sure that you have started /analytics/bin/wso2server.sh and /broker/bin/wso2.sh.

We assumed previous emm can be run normally without DAS(analytics) support so we did not run analytics base on IoT3.0, but we were wrong.